# Why this ( &#39; ) coming when I add dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, dom-events, dynamically-generated

Why this unwanted characters added with dynamically created textbox? How to take that out

```
onkeyup="numeri_validator(this,&#39;clockin_100001_1&#39;,&#39;total_100001_1&#39;)"
```

This is code behind

```
string s="numeri_validator(this,'" + textboxClockIn.ID.ToString() + "','"+textboxTotal.ID.ToString()+"')";

            string decodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);

            textboxClockIn.Attributes.Add("onkeyup",decodedString);
            textboxClockOut.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "numeri_validator(this,'" + textboxClockOut.ID + "','" + textboxTotal.ID + "')");
```

Both with the same result.

When I break this is my break result:

```
numeri_validator(this,'clockin_100001_1','total_100001_1')
```

Please advise me

Comment: Your character isn't really unwanted. &#39; is the representation of ', just as you want it.

Comment: but javascript is taking this as a parameter value how to avoid this

Answer (score 2):

This is actually exactly what is expected. What has happened is that your code has 'escaped' all the characters which could cause issues with HTML or SQL. If it didn't do this, you could get weird results where your text ends unexpectedly or has the wrong data.

in this case, the `'` symbols which you have in your string are changed to their escaped version, in this case '.

If you don't want this to happen, then you shouldn't use HTMLDecode(). However, this is not recommended because it could cause issues if you try to parse that code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Javascript will not confuse with this ( &#39 ; ) it will take as a ' but if you are dynamically creating the controls then you need to be little care full of the ID that is assigned by the .net it will cause problem if you are not aware of that

Thanks